# finding vendor_id using proc/cpuinfo

Tags: c, linux

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
char* get_cpu_vendor_id ()
{

 FILE* fp; 
 char buffer[1024]; 
 size_t bytes_read; 
 char* match; 
 char* vendor_id; 

 fp = fopen ("/proc/cpuinfo", "rb"); 

 bytes_read = fread (buffer, 1, sizeof (buffer), fp); 

 fclose (fp); 


 if (bytes_read == 0 || bytes_read == sizeof (buffer)) 
     return 0; 

 buffer[bytes_read] == '\0'; 

 match = strstr (buffer, "vendor_id"); 
 printf("%s", match);

 if (match == NULL) 
     return 0; 

 sscanf (match, "vendor_id : %s", vendor_id);
 return vendor_id; 

} 

int main () 
{
 printf ("Vendor ID Of The Processor: %s\n", get_cpu_vendor_id ()); 

 return 0; 
}
```

it works fine but  i don't want to print the whole bunch of information so when i remove the statement `printf("%s", match);` function `get_cpu_vendor_id()` returns any arbitrary value I'm unable to understand the fault

Comment: @bigbounty whats the issue here

Comment: One possible way is to use regex or according to your code,you need to allocate some memory for sscanf.

Answer (score 1):

```
sscanf (match, "vendor_id : %s", vendor_id);
```

You don't have room to store the string, reserve space before using `sscanf`:

```
vendor_id = malloc(some_size);
```

And here:

```
buffer[bytes_read] == '\0';
```

you are comparing the trailing character with 0, you want:

```
buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
```

Finally, notice that `"%s"` stops scanning at the first blank character, in this case

```
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
```

it stops after `:`, use `"%[^\n]"` to consume the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

vendor_id is not allocated any memory, you should allocate memory using malloc then use it